# React Native upload image using Expo gives errors randomly on iOS

Tags: react-native, image-uploading, multipartform-data, expo

I am uploading an image to a server,  imageUri is taken via expo's ImagePicker, here is the code:

```
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('picture', { uri: imageUri, name: filename, type })
  await fetch(uploadProfileImageURL, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    header: {
       Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  })
```

On android it works like a charm, but on iOS devices its random, 50% of time it works, and the rest time it gives iOS network error:

> "Error processing request body: Error
>   Domain=ABI25_0_RCTErrorDomainCode=0 "Invalid request Token."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid request token.}"

- URL where I am uploading is HTTPS
- Tried promises instead of async/await but no luck If I try to upload
  to a different server, problem is the same, so its not a server side
  problem
- I tried using axios/XHR but still same error. The only time error
  goes, is when I do not append image. If I append string key/values
  then it works, but if I append image it randomly does not work. I
  have tested on 3 different iOS devices, have same problem. Using
  latest expo sdk.
- If I use try/catch or .catch (when using promises) the error is not
  being caught
- On iOS simulator it works 100% of the time

Comment: Hi, What was the reason for this error? I have exact same scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading **expo** version to latest one by that time fixed the issue. Also some users experienced same problems when using **expo-pixi**. Again, upgrading the version of **expo-pixi** solves it.

Comment: Thank you. I was facing the same issue. I simply deleted the Expo App from my iPhone and reinstalled it. Now it is working absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the error was the **type extension**, in **formData**. Try to set it dynamically.